# TensorFlow multithreading StatusNotOK

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a decoupled training queue in tensorflow

at the very beginning im initilizing the graph

```
def init(self,restore,network_name):


    self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    (some other stuff)

    self.data_a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,9])
    self.data_b = tf.placeholder(tf.int8, [1, 162])
    self.q =  tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=100000,
        dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int8],
        shapes=[[1,9], [1,162]]
    )
    self.enqueue_op = self.q.enqueue([self.data_a,
                                      self.data_b])
   self.sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

In the main program I have two threads.

the first enqueues new data that is generated by my main program:

```
def load_and_enqueue(self, observations):
        _data_a = [d[0] for d in observations]
        _data_b = [d[1] for d in observations]

        self.sess.run(self.enqueue_op, feed_dict={self.data_a: _data_a,
                                                  self.data_b:_data_b})
```

the training function is called by another thread or the mainprogram this doesnt matter because it generates the same error

```
def train(self):

        tensor_a,tensor_b= self.q.dequeue_many(200)

        data_a,data_b= self.sess.run([tensor_a,tensor_b])        
        # do something meaningful
```

after a while it happens that if `self.sess.run([tensor_a,tensor_b])` is called I'm getting the following error

```
return tf_session.TF_Run(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list)
tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow.StatusNotOK: Not found: FetchOutputs node FIFOQueue_DequeueMany_39:0: not found
```

I believe it is some sort of race condition but I dont now how to fix it. any help would be really nice

Answer (score 0):

Ok it appears it that tf.graph was not thread safe for this operation in version 0.7.1 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/acac487ac4ebaa6edb3e3f866d41cbd12546a107

after upgrading to 0.10.0 the error did not appear anymore